# How to migrate from string column to foreign key pointing to row in other table with same string value in Laravel?

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-5, foreign-keys, migration

I am using Laravel 5.6 and need some help migrating a column from a populated table preserving the content logic. There is a table `pages` with a column named `icon` that accepts `string` values.

Ex:

```
Schema::create('pages', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        ...
        $table->string('icon')->nullable();
}
```

The `pages` table is populated and the `icon` column, being nullable, is not always used.

A new `icons` table was created to store all the usable icon classes.

Ex:

```
Schema::create('icons', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
});
```

How can i migrate the `icon` column from the `pages` table to be a foreign key that points to the `icons` table row that has the same value in the `name` column or null if not populated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest a polymorphic `many-to-many` approach here so that `icons` are reusable and don't require a bunch of pivot tables, should you want `icons` on something other than a page.

```
Schema::create('icons', function(Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
});

Schema::create('iconables', function(Blueprint $table) {
    $table->integer('icon_id');
    $table->integer('iconables_id');
    $table->integer('iconables_type');
});
```

Now you just need to determine if the pages have an existing `Icon`. If they do, then hold reference to them so you can insert them:

```
$pagesWithIcons = Page::whereNotNull('icon')->get();
```

At this point you need to define the polymorphic relations in your models:

```
// icon

class Icon extends Model
{
    public function pages()
    {
         return $this->morphedByMany(Page::class, 'iconable');
    }
}

// page

class Page extends Model
{
    public function pages()
    {
         return $this->morphToMany(Icon::class, 'iconable');
    }
}
```

Now you just need to create the `icons` (back in our migration), and then attach them if they exist:

```
$pagesWithIcons->each(function(Page $page) {
    $icon = Icon::firstOrNew([
        'name' => $page->icon
    });

    $icon->pages()->attach($page);
});
```

The above is creating an `Icon` if it doesn't exist, or querying for it if it does. Then it's attaching the page to that `icon`. As polymorphic `many-to-many` relationships just use `belongsToMany()` methods under the hood, you have all of the available operations at your leisure if this doesn't suite your needs.

Finally, drop your `icons` column from pages, you don't need it.

```
Schema::table('pages', function(Blueprint $table) {
    $table->dropColumn('icon');
});
```

And if you need to backfill support for only an individual `icon` (as the `many-to-many` will now return an array relationship), you may add the following to your `page` model:

```
public function icon()
{
    return $this->icons()->first();
}
```

Apologies if typos, I did this on my phone so there may be some mistakes.